# Aero - Windows 7 aero themes are greyed out

Tags: windows-7, themes, aero

I tried with all options:

1. To start Themes Service, Desktop Windows manager, etc. all the running.
2. I also tried "gpedit.msc" > and set Prevent Theme Changes setting to "Not Configured", etc.
3. I also ran the "Re-run assessment" for the Aero, it is completed, but no effect after that. But, I see that 3D is enabled in my graphics.

But nothing seems to get the Aero themes enabled, they are all greyed out.

My laptop is provided by my company, I have admin rights, but I am not getting how to enable the aero themes.

How can I enable Aero themes?

Comment: run gpresult >gpresult.txt (it will save the result to a file) - after doing that look through the visual settings. If you are restricted to something like Windows 7 Basic Colors (or something like that) it will prevent Aero themes. There are a couple visual options to check through. Start there or post the result (filter out important stuff obviously) and we can go from there :)

Answer (score 0):

Click the Start button and type "aero".
Then click on “Find and fix problems with transparency and other visual effects”.